# Seaborn Matplotlib: Get custom legend outside of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a function that generates up to 4 different plots at once. The legend needs to be saved separately from the plot.

In my code I collect all of the labels and even create some for the peaks in the bar graphs.

I then display them separately but for some reason the plot is coming out blank.

Code:

```
degree = ' \u2109 '



def generate_graph_image():
    filename = 'test_bar.png'
    legend_file_name = 'legend.png'
    bar = True

    unit = 'Kw'
    time = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

    current_temperatures = [35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 100, 85, 65, 45, 35]
    # list is not always provided
    historic_temperatures = [35, 85,  35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 95, 100, 85, 65, 45,]

    current_readings = [.99, .75, .55, .10, .35, .05, .05, .08, .20, .55, .60, .85]
    # list is not always provided
    historic_readings = [.50, .05, .05, .08, .20,  .75, .55, .10, .35,.45, .65, .49, ]

    swap = True if sum(historic_readings) > sum(current_readings) else False

    time_label = 'Month'

    temp_label = f'Temperatures {degree}'
   
    current_data = {time_label: time, unit: current_readings, temp_label: current_temperatures}
    historic_data = {time_label: time, unit: historic_readings, temp_label: historic_temperatures}

    current_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(current_data)
    historic_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(historic_data)

    fig, current_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
    current_color = 'blue'
    current_palette = "Reds"
    historic_color = 'black'
    historic_palette = "Blues_r"

    historic_ax = current_ax.twinx()
    historic_ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    historic_ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    historic_ax.axes.set_ylim(current_ax.axes.get_ylim())

    current_ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=16)
    current_ax.set_ylabel(unit, fontsize=16, )

    current_peak = max(current_readings)
    current_peak_index = current_readings.index(current_peak)

    historic_peak = max(historic_readings)
    historic_peak_index = historic_readings.index(historic_peak)

    current_ax = sns.barplot(ax=current_ax, x=time_label, y=unit, data=current_data_frame, palette=current_palette, color=current_color, )
    current_ax.patches[current_peak_index].set_color('red')
    current_ax.patches[historic_peak_index].set_alpha(0.3)

    historic_ax = sns.barplot(ax=historic_ax, x=time_label, y=unit, data=historic_data_frame, palette=historic_palette,   color=historic_color, alpha=.7)
    historic_ax.patches[historic_peak_index].set_color('black')

    temperature_ax = current_ax.twinx()
    current_color = 'green'
    historic_color = 'orange'

    temperature_ax.set_ylabel(f'Temperature {degree}', fontsize=16,)
    temperature_ax = sns.lineplot(x=time_label, y=temp_label, data=current_data_frame, sort=False, color=current_color)
    temperature_ax.tick_params(axis='y', color=current_color
    temperature_ax = sns.lineplot(x=time_label, y=temp_label, data=historic_data_frame, sort=False, color=historic_color)
    temperature_ax.tick_params(axis='y', color=historic_color)

    plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')
    plt.style.use('ggplot')

    plt.savefig(fname=filename, dpi=200)

    figsize = (2.3, 2.3)
    fig_leg = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    fig_leg.set_size_inches(2.3, 2.3, forward=True)
    ax_leg = fig_leg.add_subplot(111)

    current_peak_reading_label = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label=f'Current Peak ({unit})')
    current_reading_label = mpatches.Patch(color='purple', label=f'Current {unit}')
    historic_peak_reading_label = mpatches.Patch(color='pink', label=f'Historic Peak ({unit})')
    historic_reading_label = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow', label=f'Historic {unit}')

    handles, labels = current_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles += [current_reading_label, current_peak_reading_label, historic_reading_label, historic_peak_reading_label]

    historic_handles, historic_labels = historic_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles += historic_handles
    labels += historic_labels
    temp_handles, temp_labels = temperature_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles += temp_handles
    labels += temp_labels
    ax_leg.legend(handles, labels, loc='center', frameon=False)
    # hide the axes frame and the x/y labels
    ax_leg.axis('off')
    fig_leg.savefig(legend_file_name, dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight')

    plt.show()
```

Output:[image]

Comment: Good that you have included a complete runnable example. Could you reduce the code a bit to the point that it would be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @np8 I've simplified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, unless you use `hue`, `seaborn` plots will not render a legend. Therefore, your `handles` and `labels` originate empty. Additionally, while the `mpatches` section populates `handles`, you keep `labels` empty and not being equal in length, no legend is rendered in final.

Consider adjustments to your current code by sections (full code in link at bottom). However, below is for demonstration. Adjust process with understanding of above `hue` and `mpatches` labels issues.

**Data** *(add period column for `hue` argument)*

```
current_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(current_data).assign(period='current')
#    Month    Kw  Temperatures  ℉   period
# 0    Jan  0.99                35  current
# 1    Feb  0.75                45  current
# 2    Mar  0.55                55  current
# 3    Apr  0.10                65  current
# 4    May  0.35                75  current
# 5   June  0.05                85  current
# 6   July  0.05                95  current
# 7    Aug  0.08               100  current
# 8    Sep  0.20                85  current
# 9    Oct  0.55                65  current
# 10   Nov  0.60                45  current
# 11   Dec  0.85                35  current

historic_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(historic_data).assign(period='historic')
#    Month    Kw  Temperatures  ℉    period
# 0    Jan  0.50                35  historic
# 1    Feb  0.05                85  historic
# 2    Mar  0.05                35  historic
# 3    Apr  0.08                45  historic
# 4    May  0.20                55  historic
# 5   June  0.75                65  historic
# 6   July  0.55                75  historic
# 7    Aug  0.10                95  historic
# 8    Sep  0.35               100  historic
# 9    Oct  0.45                85  historic
# 10   Nov  0.65                65  historic
# 11   Dec  0.49                45  historic
```

**Barplot** *(call `.get_legend().remove()` to remove from original plot)*

```
current_ax = sns.barplot(ax=current_ax, x=time_label, y=unit, hue='period', data=current_data_frame, palette=current_palette, color=current_color, )
current_ax.patches[current_peak_index].set_color('red')
current_ax.patches[historic_peak_index].set_alpha(0.3)
current_ax.get_legend().remove()

historic_ax = sns.barplot(ax=historic_ax, x=time_label, y=unit, hue='period', data=historic_data_frame, palette=historic_palette, color=historic_color, alpha=.7)
historic_ax.patches[historic_peak_index].set_color('black')
historic_ax.get_legend().remove()
```

**Line Plots**  *(call `.get_legend().remove()` to remove from original plot)*

```
temperature_ax.set_ylabel(f'Temperature {degree}', fontsize=16,)

temperature_ax = sns.lineplot(x=time_label, y=temp_label, hue='period', data=current_data_frame, sort=False, palette=['g'])
temperature_ax.tick_params(axis='y', color=current_color)
temperature_ax.get_legend().remove()

temperature_ax = sns.lineplot(x=time_label, y=temp_label, hue='period', data=historic_data_frame, sort=False, palette=['orange'])
temperature_ax.get_legend().remove()
temperature_ax.tick_params(axis='y', color=historic_color)
```

**Mpatches** *(add label for each handle)*

```
#... same mpatches code ...

handles, labels = current_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# ADD LABEL TO CORRESPOND TO HANDLE
labels += ['current_reading_label', 'current_peak_reading_label', 'historic_reading_label', 'historic_peak_reading_label']
handles += [current_reading_label, current_peak_reading_label, historic_reading_label, historic_peak_reading_label]

historic_handles, historic_labels = historic_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles += historic_handles
labels += historic_labels

temp_handles, temp_labels = temperature_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles += [temp_handles[1]] + [temp_handles[3]]   # SKIP 1ST AND 3RD ITEMS (LEGEND TITLE, 'period')
labels += [temp_labels[1]] + [temp_labels[3]]      # SKIP 1ST AND 3RD ITEMS (LEGEND TITLE, 'period')
```

<kbd>[**Full Code**](https://pastebin.com/rpt0RBfm)</kbd>

---

#### **Legend Plot** *(colors/palette need adjustment)*

[image: Legend Plot]

#### **Bar and Line Plot** *(colors/palette need adjustment)*

[image: Bar and Line Plot]

Comment: which version of seaborn and matplotlib are you using? I'm getting a ValueError for the `hue` argument.

Comment: nevermind! My mistake. This works perfectly thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to update the value handles? Example after once I get the `temp_handles` variable, how can I update to display "current temperature" instead "current"?

Comment: Simply assign `period` column in data frame as 'current temperature' instead of 'current'. By the way, with `hue`, you can combine the two similarly structured data frames (`pd.concat([current_data_frame, historic_data_frame])`) for a *single* `barplot` with `dodge = False` argument and *single* `lineplot` call. Adjust palettes as needed.

Comment: If I were to update he value of period="Current Temperature"  then the bar charts would also say Temperature. Bar chart needs to say `Current kw` while line plot says `Current Temperature`

Comment: I cameup with a solution though I'm not sure if its the correct approach. I declared `handles` and `labels` as empty lists instead of `current_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` that way only lineplot gets that label. Though I suppose I could have also redeclared the dataframes after plotting the bar graphs unless there is a way to update the period property of the dataframe.

Comment: I decided to stick with the empty list approach. Using alpha changed the color and the legend didn't reflect that change. Since I have to manually set the color, it only made since to only use `get_legend_handles_labels` for temperature.